# Pine Script Strategy Tester: winning trades coming up as losses

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, back-testing

I apologize, I know this would be a super simple fix but I am new to coding/pine script and have no idea what I'm doing but trying to learn.

I am trying to make a script that takes a trade at a specific time of the day (everyday), on a specific TF, in a specific direction depending on the candle close of the previous candle (long if downclose candle/short if upclose candle), with a set proffit/loss in pips.

The code below is what I've come up with, it seems to be working on the chart, but in the "List of Trades" tab, they're all coming up as losses, every one of them (see Screenshots for example).

Can anyone help me, greatly appreciated?

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=0, margin_short=0)

trigger_m = 0
trigger_h = 19

is_trigger_bar = (hour == trigger_h) and (minute == trigger_m)

is_buy  = is_trigger_bar and open > close
is_sell = is_trigger_bar and close > open


if (is_buy)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (is_sell)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

strategy.exit("exit", loss = 100, profit = 500)
```

[Winning Trade Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PIiV.png)

[The above trade in the results showing as a loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5yxS.png)

[More examples of winning trades coming up as losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmbV4.png)

I'm assuming it has something to do with how i am exiting the positions?

Comment: what is the symbol, timeframe? where is the entry/exit prices on 2nd screenshot?

Comment: Also, what is the exchange?

Comment: It looks fine on my end.

Comment: why is the trade in the 1st photo coming up as a loss in the 2nd photo then?

Comment: We can only tell you when you answer our questions in the comments.

Comment: Ah don't worry I found a solution through ChatGPT XD